# makefile to compile all cpp files in all subdirs

Tags: c++, makefile, subdirectory

My repository looks like this:

```
./src/ModuleA/ModuleA.cpp
./src/ModuleA/ModuleA.h
./src/foo/ModuleB.cpp
./src/foo/ModuleB.h
./src/bar/ModuleC.cpp
./src/bar/ModuleC.h
<A few more modules>

./obj
./dep
./makefile
```

I want to create a makefile that will create a depndency file (.d) for each .cpp file into ./dep and then compile each of these .cpp file into an obj in ./obj

I don't want to state the name and path of the modules explicitly - just to take all of the directories in ./src and find the cpp file in each one and create a target rule for it.

Edit: I'm using windows.

Comment: Dependency `.d` files are usually generated with appropriate compiler options of the c++ compiler. E.g. for `g++` it's the `--MM`, `--MD` option family. See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801532/make-include-directive-and-dependency-generation-with-mm) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979912/problem-generating-dependencies-in-makefile-using-mm) (probably many more).

Comment: BTW, I found it easier to keep the `.d` files along with the compiled `.o` files than having them in a separate directory. Makes `clean:` targets more _clean_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working minimalist Makefile under Windows:

```
SRC         :=  $(patsubst $(shell CHDIR )\\%.cpp,%.cpp,$(shell DIR *.cpp /S /B))
OBJ         :=  $(addprefix obj\, $(SRC:.cpp=.o))
DEP         :=  $(addprefix dep\, $(SRC:.cpp=.d))
CPPFLAGS    =   -MMD -MP -MF dep\$(<:.cpp=.d)

all: $(OBJ)

obj\\%.o: %.cpp
    @IF NOT EXIST obj\$(<D) MKDIR obj\$(<D)
    @IF NOT EXIST dep\$(<D) MKDIR dep\$(<D)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

-include $(DEP)
```

Subdirectories are created into `obj` and `dep` to avoid clashes if two files share the same filename but are in different subdirectories. It also avoid having source files in subdirectories being recompiled everytime `make` is invoked.

---

**UPDATE**: A more powerful version

**WINDOWS SHELL** (Vista and newer because of [`FORFILE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx) command)

```
SRCDIR := .
OBJDIR := obj
DEPDIR := dep

SRCS     := $(shell FORFILES /P $(SRCDIR) /S /M *.cpp /C "CMD /C ECHO @relpath")
SRCS     := $(patsubst ".\\%",$(SRCDIR)\\%,$(SRCS))
OBJS     := $(SRCS:$(SRCDIR)\\%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)\\%.o)
DEPS     := $(SRCS:$(SRCDIR)\\%.cpp=$(DEPDIR)\\%.d)
TREE     := $(patsubst %\,%,$(dir $(OBJS)))
CPPFLAGS  = -MMD -MP -MF $(<:$(SRCDIR)\\%.cpp=$(DEPDIR)\\%.d)

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(OBJS)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(OBJDIR)\\%.o: $(SRCDIR)\%.cpp | $$(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(TREE): %:
    MKDIR $@
    MKDIR $(@:$(OBJDIR)%=$(DEPDIR)%)

clean:
    IF EXIST $(OBJDIR) RMDIR /S /Q $(OBJDIR)
    IF EXIST $(DEPDIR) RMDIR /S /Q $(DEPDIR)

ifeq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" ""
-include $(DEPS)
endif
```

**UNIX SHELL**

```
SRCDIR := .
OBJDIR := obj
DEPDIR := dep

SRCS     := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -name "*.cpp")
OBJS     := $(SRCS:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
DEPS     := $(SRCS:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(DEPDIR)/%.d)
TREE     := $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(OBJS)))
CPPFLAGS  = -MMD -MP -MF $(@:$(OBJDIR)/%.o=$(DEPDIR)/%.d)

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(OBJS)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp | $$(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(TREE): %:
    mkdir -p $@
    mkdir -p $(@:$(OBJDIR)%=$(DEPDIR)%)

clean:
    $(RM) -r $(OBJDIR) $(DEPDIR)

ifeq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" ""
-include $(DEPS)
endif
```

Comment: Is it possible not to create subdirs in .\obj' ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest makefiles you can do is as follows:

```
OBJDIR   = .srcobjs

SRCS    := $(shell find . -name '*.cpp')
SRCDIRS := $(shell find . -name '*.cpp' -exec dirname {} \; | uniq)
OBJS    := $(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))
DEPS    := $(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.d,$(SRCS))

DEBUG    = -g
INCLUDES = -I./Include
CXXFLAGS = $(DEBUG) -Wall -pedantic $(INCLUDES) -c

DEPENDS  = -MT $@ -MD -MP -MF $(subst .o,.d,$@)
```

It will find all the .cpp files and compile them.

Comment: There's no reason to `find` twice. You've already got the list of `*.cpp` files in `$(SRCS)`. (If you use a bit of make magic you can avoid using the shell for `SRCDIRS` entirely.)

Comment: I failed to mention that I use windows. So 'find' isn't available

Comment: Is there any way to make some polyfill for find on windows?